# How to add background Image to each item in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

So I'm using [React Native Super Grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-super-grid) to display a Section grid that looks like this:

```
 const [items] = React.useState([
    //Plants
    {
      name: 'Orchid',
      price: '0$',
      uri:
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/28/11/19/flower-743373_1280.jpg'
    },
```

and my problem is that I need the uri of each item in the items list to display as a `<ImageBackground>` but I'm not sure why `<ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={item.uri} />` doesn't work.

For now I created a const to test the image and it looks like this:

```
  const images = {
    uri: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/28/11/19/flower-743373_1280.jpg'
  }
```

and how it's rendered:

```
              <View style={[styles.itemContainer]}>
            <ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={images} />
            <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemPrice}>{item.price}</Text>
```

But I need for each uri in `const[items]` to be redered just like `item.name` and `item.price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your both text in imageBackground and check [See Details about ImageBackground here.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground)

```
      <ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={images} >
            <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemPrice}>{item.price}</Text>
     </ImageBackGroung>
```

Comment: ok but how do I have a different image for every item? I want to add several uri's

Comment: source={{uri:item.uri}} use this in your imageBackground like you do in text